# Spark Streaming to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I'm trying to replicate this example [Streamlining Search Indexing using Elastic Search](http://spark-summit.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Streamlining-Search-Indexing-using-Elastic-Search-and-Spark-Holden-Karau.pdf) by Holden Karau using the Spark Java API. I've successfully made it work as a normal Java application with some changes in the code. Instead of using `saveAsHadoopDataset` method I'm sending my tweets with:

```
   JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(rdd,"/test/collection");
```

and running my code with:

```
 java -cp ./target/hbase-spark-playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar spark.examples.SparkToElasticSearchStreaming local[2] collection-name
```

My current problem is how to execute it on a Yarn Cluster. A code snippet of what I'm doing can be found here:

```
https://gist.github.com/IvanFernandez/b3a3e25397f8b402256b
```

and running my class this way:

```
spark.examples.SparkToElasticSearchStreaming --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 400m --num-executors 1 ./target/hbase-spark-playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar yarn-cluster collection-name
```

I think that the main problem is that I don't have any elasticSearch configuration in the foreach transformation so I can't reach my elasticSearch master. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The es cluster or other configuration information should be set in the SparkConf, which is already done in your code snippet as args[2] set as es.nodes. In your yarn command the third argument with es host is missing, also I believe that your command is using spark-submit to submit the application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try setting the **`spark.es.nodes`** and **`es.port`** properties in as shown below in SparkConf:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.es.nodes", args[2]);
sparkConf.set("es.port", args[3]);   // HTTP Port of elastic search
```

And use the below command to run the app on yarn:

```
spark-submit --class spark.examples.SparkToElasticSearchStreaming --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 400m --num-executors 1 ./target/hbase-spark-playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar yarn-cluster collection-name localhost 9200
```